# Transform data of string to a string of list

Tags: python

The sample file.text is like:

```
+++++Host: 192.168.1.1+++++
Port Number: 80
......
product: Apache httpd
IP Address: 192.168.1.1

+++++Host: 192.168.1.2+++++
Port Number: 80
......
product: Apache http
IP Address: 192.168.1.2

+++++Host: 192.168.1.3+++++
Port Number: 80
......
product: Apache httpd
IP Address: 192.168.1.3

+++++Host: 192.168.1.4+++++
Port Number: 80
......
product: Apache httpd
IP Address: 192.168.1.4

+++++Host: 192.168.1.5+++++
Port Number: 80
......
product: Apache httpd
IP Address: 192.168.1.5
```

-------------------This is the code I used-----------------------------

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.read()
    text_lines = rows.split('+++++')
    httpHostList = []
    for i, row in enumerate(text_lines):
        if 'http' in str(row):
            hosts = text_lines[i - 1].strip("Host: ")
            print(httpHostList)
```

I have got few IP addresses from `httpHostList` as followings

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

To get the followings:

```
[['192.168.1.1'],
['192.168.1.2'],
['192.168.1.3'],
['192.168.1.4'],
['192.168.1.5']]
```

I tried `httpHostList.append(hosts)` but it did not give me the result I want.

How can I convert them to the expected format?

Comment: is hostsAddress a list of str?

Comment: @ksooklall they are string in a file

Comment: empty_list = [].  empty_list.append([hostsAddress]) for each host address.

Comment: how come `print(type(hostsAddress))` yields 5 lines of output? What is `hostsAddress`?

Comment: I have edited the file to make more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you want list of lists containing host addresses. try adding this after last line

```
httpHostList.append([hosts])
```